# ¿ Porqué mi servi worker no corre en la Versión 96.0.4664.45 e chorome?

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc

Cree un servi worker con js para un sistema, Registra, instala, activa y actualiza, actualmente la versión de mi navegador es  Versión 96.0.4664.45, al publicar no corre el sw en mi navegador, al probarlo en navegador de versión 6 si funciona el sw.  Lo que no entiendo porque se da esta situación se supone que el sw es compatible con chorome no importa la versión.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ALgún mensaje en consola, algún detalle del service worker que nos quieras compartir para no tener que adivinar? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!